# Sanitizing data before storing it might mean stored data is different to what the user entered - is that common practice?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

**The Background**

HTML form, e.g. for a user to submit their business details which will later appear on a legal document - so data needs to be precise.

Submits to a PHP script that validates all inputs.

If all inputs are valid, it sanitizes the data and writes it to a database using parameterised queries.

If any of the inputs are invalid, it re-displays the form. My feeling is that the user would expect this form to be populated with what they originally typed in with some feedback on what is wrong with their input. They can then amend their input and re-submit the form. This means the form needs to be populated with *unsanitized* data (this will be escaped before displaying it).

All good so far.

**The Problem**

If the data is valid, it is written to a database. Best practice seems to be to sanitize the data before sending it to the database.

This means the data written to the database might not be exactly what the user typed in (e.g. if sanitization removes some "dangerous" characters).

This seems like a poor user experience to me.

I'm using PHP and the code is running within the WordPress framework. WP has its own sanitization functions and they recommend always sanitizing input before using it. They also suggest using PHP's santization features too. But nothing seems to address the issue that sanitizing data before storing it might result in saved data being different from what the user entered.

**The Question**

What I'd like is a description of an approach that's been used in the real world that addresses this issue? Or some feedback from those of you more experience than I am, that this is not a problem in the real world and it's common practice just to sanitize data and store it without further concern or feedback to the user.

**My thoughts about possible solutions**

A more thorough pattern would be to consider unsanitary data as invalid and feedback to the user what is wrong with their input. But this seems impractical and would require fairly long sanitization functions to provide any specific and useful feedback to the user. It also renders existing WP/PHP sanitization functions somewhat irrelevant.

A practical compromise may be to compare sanitized data with raw data and then simply notify the user that something got cleaned up before it was saved... so they can at least check the saved data to make sure they're happy with it.

Thanks for your help.

**Conclusions**

The answer I've accepted was helpful and lead me to a solution to my particular use case, but I wanted to add a few points of my own.

Firstly, on re-reading the WP documentation I found that it's not recommending to validate AND then sanitize before writing to a database. It recommends to validate, but suggests sanitizing the input might be more convenient if the particular situation does not require strict validation. It also says use one or the other, not both. So I don't think the WP documentation is wrong on this, I just misread it.

Secondly, I didn't understand that parameterized queries are so effective against SQL injection. So I figured that sanitizing input before using it in a DB query was a sensible thing to do. But it seems it's not necessary.

And finally, I now realise that it's all about context... the issue is making data safe *for a particular use*. In that sense, it's not that one technique is only appropriate for input and another technique is only appropriate for output. I need to think about validating, sanitizing or escaping when doing anything with the data - e.g. write it to a DB, use it in a calculation, print it to screen, or inject it into a PDF document. And in all cases, I just need to think about how I make it safe for that particular use. Sanitizing "input" might be entirely appropriate - if it's quick and easy, makes the data safe for whatever I need to do and doesn't render the data inaccurate. Another example is the WordPress function esc_url_raw() which the manual says is specifically to be used when storing a URL in the database. So again, the idea that escaping is only appropriate for "output" is misleading.

I ended up validating the input before writing it to the database. I did not need to sanitize it aswell. So I if it's invalid, I tell the user. If it's valid, it gets written to the DB in its original form. And I escape it before displaying it back to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Best practice seems to be to sanitize the data before sending it to the database.

This is a common misconception. Sanitization should only be performed on data that is being output, to prevent XSS for example and even then only as a last resort. Exactly because it can irreversibly destroy the original data.

Validation is your first line of defense. Make sure that the data is properly formatted, and valid within its context - just that; no looking for special characters, don't be over-zealous. If it's not valid - reject it, don't try to salvage the "good" parts from it.

Then, when storing in database, you merely need to use parameterized queries - that is 100% effective against SQL injections. If you didn't mangle the data in a previous step, you're storing it in its original form.

And finally, when the data is being output, that is where you SHOULD escape special characters within the appropriate context, so that it is properly rendered; or sanitize it if you have no other choice (i.e. the context is unclear and therefore you can't do proper escaping).

Comment: Thanks but... You say that sanitizing is about output, but this page from the WordPress Plugin Handbook https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/ has a whole section on "Securing (sanitizing) input" and that's specifically what I'm asking about... sanitizing input. I don't have a problem sanitizing (escaping) output.

Comment: As I said, it's a common misconception. Sadly, the WP manual is wrong on this too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are worried about user feelings, that's good. There are few things which you can do.
Use html form `pattern` - for sure no one name needs signs like `< > & $ " ...` - exclude this with `pattern`, use css `:invalid` and `:invalid:focus` to inform the user before submitting if something is wrong. It is very easy and simple.
Than goes php further validation and WP sanitation.
You can use intermediate state - after 'wash' - display final version (no inputs) with 2 buttons - save or correction - let the user decide, most of us don't like this repetitions "are you sure? clicking submit you mean submit?" - but maybe with so relevant content, users would like to have last chance, and they wish to see the final version (without inputs, checkboxes etc).
Now you put accepted version into db (prepared).
Comparing raw data with washed is not practical, honestly it sucks - the users won't be coders - they just won't be able to correctly understand "we sanitised your answers, and now they are 345 characters shorter. Sorry for inconvenience"
Don't worry too much
...there is a german last name 'Ei' - only 2 characters, so pattern can't require more than 2.